# How to create JIRA issue with the issuetype as BUG under specific epic ID

Tags: node.js, rest, jira, jira-plugin

I can be able to create a JIRA issue with the type of BUG
How to create this issue under already created epic on my project.

Name of the epic ID - TEST-12.

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find any documentation that related to this.

https://your-domain.atlassian.com/rest/api/3/issue

My code is as follows

```
   "fields":{
  "summary":"create BUG under epic test",
  "description":{
     "version":1,
     "type":"doc",
     "content":[
        {
           "type":"paragraph",
           "content":[
              {
                 "type":"text",
                 "text":"Please find the details"
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  "project":{
     "key":"TEST"
  },
  "issuetype":{
     "name":"Bug"
  }
```

}
}

How to create the above BUG under the epic key TEST-12 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out

Simply query the fields
https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=TEST&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields

And attach the epic link field ID as customfield_#### in the request that pointing to the epic TEST-12

I just referenced the customfield with epic link issue ID as follows
customfield_10013 : "TEST-12"

Thanks
Ahamed